# QGraphicsPixmapItem setRotation not redrawing after rotation

Tags: pyside, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicspixmapitem

I have a QGraphicsPixmapItem that I want to rotate. If I use a button on the GUI to set the rotation, it rotates fine and is redrawn fine. If I have a separate thread execute the same command (setRotation), it rotates fine every time but doesn't always redraw the item. I know it rotates because if I drag a movable object over it, it will redraw underneath it. I have recreated this in a smaller program to demonstrate. If you start the timer, and the item disappears, drag the rect over it and it will appear. How do I force it to redraw (or repaint)?

```
from PySide6 import QtWidgets
from PySide6 import QtCore
from PySide6 import QtGui
import sys
import random
import time
import threading


class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 310, 250)

        # Create 1 second timer for updating GUI
        self.update_gui_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.start_update_timer)
        self.create_ui()
        self.show()


    def rotate_random(self):
        self.rotationItem.setRotation(random.randint(1, 359))

    def start_update_timer(self):
        while True:
            self.rotationItem.setRotation(random.randint(1, 359))
            time.sleep(2)

    def create_ui(self):


        self.scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.rotationItem = self.scene.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('c130_top.png'))
        # set the origin for the transformation at the center of the pixmap
        self.rotationItem.setTransformOriginPoint(self.rotationItem.boundingRect().center())
        # ensure that the transformation is always antialiased
        self.rotationItem.setTransformationMode(QtCore.Qt.TransformationMode.SmoothTransformation)

        blue_brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.GlobalColor.blue)
        black_pen = QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.GlobalColor.black)
        black_pen.setWidth(1)

        self.rect = self.scene.addRect(0, 0, 20, 20, black_pen, blue_brush)
        self.rect.setTransformOriginPoint(self.rect.boundingRect().center())

        self.rect.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)

        self.graphicsView = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self)
        self.graphicsView.setGeometry(0, 0, 300, 200)
        self.graphicsView.setScene(self.scene)

        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Start Timer", self)
        button.setGeometry(0, 200, 100, 50)
        button.clicked.connect(self.update_gui_thread.start)

        button2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Rotate Random", self)
        button2.setGeometry(100, 200, 100, 50)
        button2.clicked.connect(self.rotate_random)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: UI elements are ***NOT*** thread-safe. Use QTimer to call a function at regular intervals.